# Is there a way to avoid amp; prepending to request parameter name in GrailsParameterMap

Tags: grails, httprequest

My request URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/application/controller/action?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2
```

I obtain request params in controller through [grails-core/WebAttributes.groovy](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-common/src/main/groovy/grails/web/api/WebAttributes.groovy)

```
/**
* Obtains the Grails parameter map
*
* @return The GrailsParameterMap instance
*/
GrailsParameterMap getParams() {
    currentRequestAttributes().getParams()
}
```

The 2nd param in the map is of structure

```
{LinkedHashMap$Entry@00000} "amp;param2" -> "value2"
```

How or is it possible to eliminate "amp;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request URL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) includes parameters named amp;param2 and similar; parameters are separated by ampersands, not HTML-encoded ampersands.  This is not a problem with Grails, but instead with however you are generating your URL.

How are you generating the request URL that you reference here?

Comment: You are right. The URL is generated like this
`url?.encodeAsHTML()`